# How to setup wordpress as linux systemd service

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx, systemd

I have multiple wordpress sites hosted on Ubuntu 22.04 which are configured through php8.1 fpm and nginx sites-available. The problem I'm facing is that I can't stop an wordpress site like a systemd service. I've previously setup django python based websites as systemd service via gunicorn wsgi server to control them locally. Is this possible to configure wordpress website as systemd service ?

Comment: Why would you want to "stop a WordPress website"? :-)

Answer (score -1):

Most people run Wordpress locally with a LAMP stack or in a Docker container. A quick Google search suggests that it's possible to run Docker as a systemd service, so maybe give that a try.